# Mixing Sync and Async methods in the same HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

In their docs and examples, Microsoft says not to Mix calls to Sync and Async methods for the same `HttpWebRequest` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks)

However, in the example given, they call `request.BeginGetRequestStream`, and in the callback they complete getting the stream using `request.EndGetRequestStream`, then synchronously fills it with the user input, then continue with `request.BeginGetResponse`.

Is it okay to just call `request.GetRequestStream`, fill it up with the content of another stream using `CopyTo`, then continue to the `request.BeginGetResponse`?

For example, which is better:

Option 1:

```
void SendRequest()
{
    // here comes the creation of a request using WebRequest.CreateHttp()
    // ...
   
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.BeginGetRequestStream(GetRequestStreamCallback, request);
}

private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    this.someBodyContentStream.CopyTo(postStream);
    postStream.Close();
    request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
}
```

or Option 2:

```
void SendRequest()
{
    // here comes the creation of a request using WebRequest.CreateHttp()
    // ...
   
    request.Method = "POST";
    Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    this.someBodyContentStream.CopyTo(postStream);
    request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
}
```

## Update

Is it possible that a call to a `Begin...` method that takes a callback and an object and returns an `IAsyncResult` will call the callback on the same thread, thus, if not handled correctly, will cause a hang in case the callback releases a wait-handle?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? You almost certainly should be using `System.Net.HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: There is no advantage to reading a stream Async since you cannot send the request until the entire stream is read into body.

Comment: @Crowcoder We are targeting all .net versions 4.5 and up, all .net core versions 2.0 and up, and .net 5.0.

Comment: @jdweng that's what I thought, but it seems the official documentation says otherwise. Can you think of a scenario where it makes sense?
The code is already written but it sometimes hangs, and while I fixed most places I could find and/or think of I still can't allow it to be released if I don't fully understand the reason for the hangs.

Comment: How many bytes in the body?  The max size of a TCP payload ~1500 bytes.  TCP allows for chunks to get spit and combined during routing.  If it hangs, it means the length in first packet to not match total size or the connection closed.  The easiest thing to check is from cmd.exe >Netstat -a which will give the status of the connection.  It should be closed if all the data was received.

Comment: @jdweng problem is it's rarely reproduces on my machine, and on the CI server (we use Travis CI currently) I also didn't see it happen in a while. But that doesn't mean the issue is gone and I need to understand why. If it helps, we run hundreds of tests in one suite, about 6 in parallel. On another suite we run about 30 tests.